# PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Android]

Tags: windows, android-studio

After updating Users directory, my Android emulator always crashes. This change also affects other configurations, like [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/1033).

```
PS C:\Users\CurrentUsername> emulator.exe "@expr"
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\OldUsername\.android\avd\expr.avd\config.ini for reading.
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\OldUsername\.android\avd\expr.avd\config.ini for reading. (3x)
INFO    | AVD expr has path C:\Users\OldUsername\.android\avd\expr.avd
INFO    | trying to check whether C:\Android is a valid sdk root
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\OldUsername\.android\avd\expr.avd\config.ini for reading.
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\OldUsername\.android\avd\expr.avd\config.ini for reading.
WARNING | emulator has searched the above paths but found no valid sdk root directory.
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Android]!
```

How do I solve this configuration mismatch?

I expect that Android emulator run properly on my machine after updating users directory name. I've also looked at other similar problems, but it seems the solution does not work for my case.

Comment: "*the solution does not work for my case"* - What solutions did you try? There are already a couple questions regarding this issue

Answer (score 2):

Updating the path on **"C:\Users\CurrentUser\.android\<avdname>\<avdname>.ini"** solved the problem.